# How can I calculate the distance to the closest player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I calculate distance to the closest player and show it via a scoreboard on a vanilla server?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank yes, but there are many small problems (like how to get absolute value when I subtract coordinates, etc) _seems you a bot btw_

Comment: Do you need to do this with a vanilla server? It can be done easily on Bukkit.

Comment: I'd recommend adding that effort to your question; you'll get a better response.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 Yes. As I have restricted environment (Realms)

Comment: @Frank I already have 2 downvotes for nothing. And no experience at all in minecraft block programming. So while I will be trying to describe what I tried, I'll get another 3 downvotes and will be forced to delete question.

Comment: Downotes can always be turned into upvotes by the voters, once the question is asked properly.. just give it a try.If a question contains enough information and (if applicable) a portion of self-effort you will likely earn some upvotes and have a higher chance of getting the question answered.

Comment: You currently have two downvotes because you don't display any effort to solve your problem; check the downvote tooltip.  `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`.  Show some effort, and you'll be fine.

Comment: *"yes, but there are many small problems (like how to get absolute value when I subtract coordinates, etc)"* - could you put what you've got so far in your question? It sounds like you're pretty close to a solution if you've found how to get the coordinates and subtract them.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone tried to look up how this problem could be accomplished, because this is the first result from google search. And I happened to work it out.

You can do this in 1.13+ now, with the `/execute store` command

The steps are as follows: store player coordinates > calculate the differences > square the differences > sum up > calculate the sqrt values. I'm using euclidean distance as the metric.

1. Store Player Coordinates:
You'd need to define objectives to store the values, I defined them as `"X", "Y", and "Z"`

```
execute as @a run execute store result score @s X run data get entity @s Pos[0]
execute as @a run execute store result score @s Y run data get entity @s Pos[1]
execute as @a run execute store result score @s Z run data get entity @s Pos[2]
```

2. Calculate the Differences:
I defined another set of objectives to store the results `"X_difference", "Y_difference", "Z_difference"`, but you don't have to.

```
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s X_difference = @s X
execute at @a run scoreboard players operation @s X_difference -= @p[sort=nearest] X
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s Y_difference = @s Y
execute at @a run scoreboard players operation @s Y_difference -= @p[sort=nearest] Y
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s Z_difference = @s Z
execute at @a run scoreboard players operation @s Z_difference -= @p[sort=nearest] Z
```

3. Square the Differences:

```
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s X_difference *= @s X_difference
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s Y_difference *= @s Y_difference
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s Z_difference *= @s Z_difference
```

4. Sum Up: 
   I defined another objective `"distance"` to store the sum of the squared values from 3.

```
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s distance = @s X_difference
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s distance += @s Y_difference
execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s distance += @s Z_difference
```

5. Approximate the Square Root Values:
   We can use a simple algorithm to calculate the square root values. You can find more info on how it works [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-write-a-program-for-finding-the-square-root-of-a-number-without-using-the-sqrt-function). We need to create three new objectives: `sqrtI`, `sqrtX` and `realDistance`. I highly recommend using a datapack to implement this, as we need to recursively get closer to the real square.

Once you have your distance value, run the following to reset the sqrt algorithm:

```
# ... every tick, after calculating distance, do:
scoreboard players set @a sqrtI 1
scoreboard players set @a sqrtX 0
scoreboard players set @a realDistance 0
# then we start the algorithm by running another function:
execute as @a if score @s distance > @s sqrtX run function mydatapack:sqrt
```

mydatapack:sqrt.mcfunction contains the following commands:

```
scoreboard players operation @s sqrtX += @s sqrtI
scoreboard players add @s realDistance 1
scoreboard players add @s sqrtI 2
execute as @s if score @s distance > @s sqrtX run function mydatapack:sqrt
```

The `realDistance` objective then contains the real distance that every single player is away from you in blocks.

Comment: On 1.18 I had to change all three `execute at @a run scoreboard players operation @s X_difference -= @p[sort=nearest] X` to `execute as @a at @s run scoreboard players operation @s X_difference -= @p[sort=nearest,distance=0.1..] X`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show the distance closest to the player and show it via scoreboard due to the fact vanilla scoreboards are used for every player. This can be easily done with some bukkit code which will be both more efficient and cleaner to the eye.

Comment: I can't install bukkit on Realms ((

Comment: For `each` player show distance to `nearest` (nothing impossible)

Comment: It is impossible! The scoreboards are not per player! Look this up yourself before you downvote the correct answer to your question.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic I think the post says this is impossible because you can't show a player their number and nobody else's. It doesn't seem to address what commands should be used.

Comment: @ash4fun Ok. I missed something, but its still not impossible (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cThnjDTxUUQ)
`PS` I didn't press any vote button on this stack yet

Comment: It is impossible! Your system only calculates the position of a player, it does not use a scoreboard