# How do I find the absolute value of a score?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I want to find the absolute value of two coordinates in Minecraft 1.16.3 to see how far apart they are.  So I make the cords into scoreboard values so I could use operations.  Could I use the pipes or '|' like in math.  How would I do it without a bunch of other commands to test if the values are below 0 or something.  If any data packs are needed that's fine.  I just wanted to know if I could do it like in normal math e.g. |1-10| that equals 9.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: While I know absolutely nothing about scoreboards in Minecraft, if you square a number and then take the square root of the result, it will give you the absolute value

Comment: Actually, I think [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310012/how-can-i-calculate-the-distance-to-the-closest-player) will give you the information you're looking for

Comment: I'm not sure entirely the exact commands on doing this, couldn't you check if its less than `0` and if it **is** then multiply it by `-1` and if **not** just leave it alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only math operations available with the scoreboard are `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, and `%=` (modulo). To get the absolute values of a score, you just need to multiply it by `-1` if it is below 0.

Note that multiplication and division cannot be done with a constant number. To multiply by, say, `-1`, we need to *set* some other score to that value and reference it in our multiplication.

The command looks like this:

```
execute if score @s score matches ..-1 run scoreboard players operation @s score *= -1 const
```

where `@s score` is the score we want to convert to absolute value, and `-1 const` is a constant score set to −1.

This command checks if the score is −1 or below, and if so, multiplies it by −1 to make it positive.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  Did you mean to type temp instead of test in the 3rd line of code in the score selector?

Comment: @randomuser922 No, I just mixed up the objective names with the actual ones on my world. (I used `test` and `abs` instead of `vals` and `temp`)